# jQuery conflict only on posts, not in pages and home (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu, conflict

I'm focusing for days to fix this problem but it seem I'm not able to.

I have a wordpress website > http://www.davidegiorgetta.com. It has a standard menu on the top, that when you'are using and iPad or smaller devices (you can try resizing the browser as well) becomes a drop-down menu, with a black button.

When you're in the home page or in another random page it works perfectly, but when you're in a post page it doesn't.

I really don't know the origin of the problem. It seems a jQuery conflict but the console log doesn't show any error.

Really hope you can suggest me a way to fix it.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not closing your tags properly, therefore the footer isn't loading, and the scripts needed to make the navbar works located in

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.davidegiorgetta.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Pronto/js/global.js?ver=1.0'></script>
```

aren't loading either.

When checking your source code, I see it ends in this line:

```
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

so I have teh feeling you forgot to add

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: The problem was just that! When I modified the single.php page I probably forgot to replace `<?php get_footer(); ?>`. Thank you so much! Never seen a problem solved in such a short time!

Comment: no problem, I build WP sites for a living and from time to time I forget simple things like that. Glad to help :)